# C++ code runs 3-fold faster on Linux mint 17.1 vs Linux 18.2

Tags: linux-mint, performance, c++

I run C++ code (consisting of differential equations and solvers etc.) on two Linux mint versions. First tried with Mint 18.2, which spent 17 minutes to finish the job. Then Mint 17.1 was installed to replace Mint 18.2 as the performance was unsatisfactory. Mint 17.1 required less than 6 minutes to finish the job and produce identical results. I was shocked by the difference in performance. Any thoughts to explain this?
Thank you!

And here's my Makefile:

```
#Makefile

CXX=g++

CXXFLAGS = -Ilib -O3 -std=c++11  -g   -march=native

LDFLAGS=  -lz 

NZ_Model_New_Ito:$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard lib/*.cpp))
```

Computer: CPU i5-3470, 8GB DDR3 RAM, 500GB drive (hp 8300 elite small form factor desktop computer (intel core i5-3470 3.2ghz quad-core, 8gb ram, 500gb sata)

Comment: Different `gcc` version?

Comment: I find it unlikely a Linux distribution version upgrade can have such a big impact on the execution time of a cpu bound application, unless the build tools are broken (like dirkt hinted above). If you want to dig deeper into this, I would recommend using profiling tools to see where the program spends its time. See [this article](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/gprof-valgrind-gperftools-evaluation-tools-application-level-cpu-profiling-linux/) on Linux profiling tools.

Comment: You haven't installed the 32-bit version of Linux Mint 18 by mistake?

Comment: @dirkt g++ was surely different on 17.1 (4.8) and 18.2 (5.+?). I tested g++4.8 on Mint 18.2 as well, and there was no improvement.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thank you. That's possible but unlikely since I double checked before flashed into memory stick. Today I replaced Mint 18.2 on my workstation (i7-7700K) in the Lab with Mint 17.1, receiving roughly 20% increase in speed.

Comment: Actually *looking* at the `gcc` version in both Mint releases, and then e.g. installing both versions on the same Mint release and *testing* would go a long way to actually narrow down the problem instead of having us guess. Floating point centered programs with `-O3` are *almost certainly* influenced by how `gcc` does optimaztions, and what the devs thought to be an improvement in the cases they tested may backfire in your case. The *next* step would be to have a closer look to what particular optimzations `-O3` translates for that `gcc`.

Comment: Having frequently accessed data aligned on a cache line vs. non-aligned can also impact performance. If the data spans two cache lines it has a negative effect on cache utilization compared to if the data is neatly arranged to fill a single cache line. If you haven't paid attention to this, it is possible that the compiler on Mint 17.1 by chance produces better code than the one on Mint 18.2.

Comment: @JohanMyréen  Thank you. I understand these factors may contribute to the performance gap, but have no energy or sufficient skills/time to test all these stuff. I am curious whether this issue is unique to me due to something special in my code, or someone else may also have seen this.